# Button not working in asp.net mvc application (environment specific)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a asp.net mvc application deployed in production. User can save a form in draft state and then can submit the form later. This functionality is working perfectly but for two of our users in Malaysia, when they click on Submit button, nothing is happening. It seems that the button is not working (page is not posted back).
I am unable to understand what could be the possible cause. If there is a firewall issue, then site would not have been opened at all. 
Can I use fiddler to check or if there are some other options?

Comment: Any chance you can use something like TeamViewer and remote-control their desktop and use the developer tools to triage what might be happening?

Comment: Yes but what to check in developer tools?

Comment: I would first look to see what is happening with the Post on the network tab (is the server returning an error? is something wrong with the url for the postback? etc.). Also, check for errors on the console tab, perhaps a js error is preventing your postback? (depending on how you form is coded). How do you know the page is not posting back to your server?